# Override Component\Filters\Type\Range for custom grid column

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, filter

I created custom admin grid with filters. But when I enter 0 in "from field" in filter - in the results it shows items with negative values also, so it does not work right.

I found this function in magento core

vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Filters\Type\Range.php

```
protected function applyFilterByType($type, $value)
{
    if (!empty($value) && $value !== '0') {
        $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setConditionType($type)
            ->setField($this->getName())
            ->setValue($value)
            ->create();

        $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addFilter($filter);
    }
}
```

If I comment this "if" statement it works right.
How can I fix this in my module? How can I override Range class for my column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In listing xml, inside < filters > tag

```
<filterRange name="amount" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\AmountRange" />
```

In Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\AmountRange.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Filters\Type;
class AmountRange extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\Range
{

/**
 * Apply filter by its type
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $value
 * @return void
 */
  protected function applyFilterByType($type, $value)
  {

        $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setConditionType($type)
            ->setField($this->getName())
            ->setValue($value)
            ->create();

        $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->addFilter($filter);

  }
}
```